# HTTP Posting issue in .NET 4.0

Tags: http-post

We have two servers, first Server's Web Application is Posting HTTP POST data to Second Server Web Application web page(aspx - this page on Load simply sends an Email). It is working fine when we configured the receiving web application(Second Server) in .NET 2.0 but not working in .NET 4(returning HTTP 5000 Server error(got this from Server Logs). So please anyone have any solution for this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is that an HTTP 5000 or 500 error, I expect it is 500.

I would suggest configuring Failed Request Tracing on your server (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725786%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which should provide further details on your 500 error.